# vslam tutorial CameraInfo error

Tags: ros, visual-odometry, vslam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am running the vslam tutorial, I achieved to compile it but like other I got an error in the vslam-tutorial.bag

$ rosbag play --clock /path/to/your/bag/vslam_tutorial.bag

Client [/wide_stereo/stereo_vslam_node] wants topic /wide_stereo/right/camera_info to have datatype/md5sum [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo/c9a58c1b0b154e0e6da7578cb991d214], but our version has [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo/1b5cf7f984c229b6141ceb3a955aa18f]. Dropping connection.

Client [/wide_stereo/stereo_vslam_node] wants topic /wide_stereo/left/camera_info to have datatype/md5sum [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo/c9a58c1b0b154e0e6da7578cb991d214], but our version has [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo/1b5cf7f984c229b6141ceb3a955aa18f]. Dropping connection.

if I still want to use the vslam-tutorial.bag, how can I change the CameraInfo or what can I do to solve this problem?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9359/vslam-tutorial-camerainfo-error/) by [jrcapriles](https://answers.ros.org/users/269/jrcapriles/) on ROS Answers with karma: 370 on 2011-03-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jrcapriles](https://answers.ros.org/users/269/jrcapriles/) on 2011-03-10**:
Cturtle on Ubuntu 10.04

**Comment by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on 2011-03-10**:
Which distribution are you running this on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried running a rosbag check and rosbag fix on the bag file?

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The same problem occurs doing the tutorial on Diamondback and the [bag file](http://pr.willowgarage.com/data/vslam_system/vslam_tutorial.bag) as of 22nd March. (md5sum is f5aece448b7af00a38a993eb71400806)

**To check:**

```
rosbag check vslam_tutorial.bag
The following migrations need to occur:
 * From: sensor_msgs/CameraInfo [1b5cf7f984c229b6141ceb3a955aa18f]
   To:   sensor_msgs/CameraInfo [c9a58c1b0b154e0e6da7578cb991d214]
```

**To fix:**

```
rosbag fix vslam_tutorial.bag vslam_tutorial_diamondback.bag
```

**To play the modified bag:**

```
rosbag play --clock vslam_tutorial_diamondback.bag
```

---

Originally posted by [rreid](https://answers.ros.org/users/323/rreid/) with karma: 124 on 2011-03-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2